# request failure with http statusCode:422,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unprocessable Entity

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm new to the group and debutant on the Android Development, month I work on a payment by paypal module, but I get an error that I'm having trouble solving. error message:![enter image description here][1]

```
request failure with http statusCode:422,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unprocessable Entity
request failed with server response:{"name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR","debug_id":"037a6be490932","message":"checkout-session not created","information_link":"https://api-m.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR"}
```

Help me please

Comment: The entity it's the information that you sends to paypal server, then probably you this formatting wrong information as waits the paypal server. Show us your entity format.

Answer (score 0):

The server response indicates the problem fairly clearly: `PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED` / `NO_VALID_FUNDING_INSTRUMENT` / `ADD_PAYMENT_CARD`. Your code is working; the payment was refused on PayPal's end because the payer account is not able to pay. Fix your test payer account, or use another known-good payer account.

One additional caution: despite the messaging suggesting the solution is to add a card to the account, that may not be enough. PayPal has to live under a variety of international legal rules, and I think that India is one country in which PayPal and the government are not getting along very well:

http://www.zdnet.com/article/paypal-puts-india-on-hold/

Comment: the problem does not come from my code but from my account if I understand. when I sandbox for testing I had no problem, but when I'm going into production I had this message I above post. how to check if my company paypal account is correct?
What the country (Cameroon) where I am does not pose problem?